# Change empty string to NULL when column has DATE constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, insert, create-table

This might be impossible but I was wondering if someone more experienced knew if this is possible to do in postgresql.

I have a column in my create statement

`CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS (other cols, some_date DATE, other cols);`

When I extract the json object from the API, there might actually be an empty string '' instead of a empty cell. Which of course gives me the following error `psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: ""`

The solution would simply to change the constraint to VARCHAR, but i was wondering if there was some way in the `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements to say the following pseudo code: `if empty string insert NULL`.

Comment: If all else fails, you could import to a staging table then insert from there with a `case` on the insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` in your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (cols..., some_date) VALUES (..., NULLIF(your_input_field, ''))
```

If you want to insert NULL if the value in question is any of a number of values, it may be easiest to use a CASE statement:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (cols..., some_date)
VALUES (..., CASE WHEN your_input_field IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE your_input_field END)
```

Could do the same with an array as well, if that's easier:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (cols..., some_date)
VALUES (..., CASE WHEN your_input_field = ANY('{"",#,-,--,??}'::TEXT[]) THEN NULL ELSE your_input_field END)
```

Comment: Thanks! `your_input_field` should be replaced by `some_date`?

Comment: `your_input_field` is the JSON field value you want to insert in the `some_date` field in your table, which could be an empty string. Doing a `NULLIF` on the value will return NULL if the value of the first parameter is equal to the value of the second parameter. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Jackpot would be if I could insert a `NULL` for a list of strings like `#` `-` `--` `??` etc... the so-called NITS (nothing interesting to say).

Comment: Holy crap you just helped me so much!! Thousands thanks : ))

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: I don't want to ask for too much - but i'm trying to convert this into a psycopg2 command but it doesn't work, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260366/insert-into-table-with-type-casting-and-condition-in-insert-statement/56260573#56260573

Comment: @TytireRecubans I've posted an answer on that question, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the solution posted by 404 that checks what we are trying to insert in our db is a NITS (nothing interesting to say), and replace it with `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
   ID             VARCHAR,
   NAME           VARCHAR,
   AGE            VARCHAR,
   ADDRESS        VARCHAR,
   DATE           INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, DATE)
VALUES (CASE WHEN cast('a' as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE 'a' END,
        CASE WHEN cast('gino' as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE 'gino' END,
        CASE WHEN cast('' as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??', 'na') THEN NULL ELSE '' END,
        CASE WHEN cast('via figa' as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE 'via figa' END,
        CASE WHEN cast(1 as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE 1  END);
```