# Insert into table with type casting and condition in INSERT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, psycopg2

Based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258007/change-empty-string-to-null-when-column-has-date-constraint/56258382?noredirect=1#comment99134711_56258382)

I am trying to compose an insert statement in Python using psycopg2 with some data. The query works beautifully in postgresql console but when I try it from psycopg2 I get an error.

Here's the table i want to insert to

```
create_test_table = """CREATE TABLE persons(
   name           VARCHAR,
   age            INT,
   dob            DATE,
   sex            VARCHAR);"""
```

Here's the data I want to insert

`d_ = {"name":"Gino", "age": "", "dob": "na", "sex": "M"}`

And here's my query:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO persons (age,dob,sex,name) 
               VALUES (CASE WHEN cast(%(age)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(age)s END,
                       CASE WHEN cast(%(dob)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(dob)s END,
                       CASE WHEN cast(%(sex)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(sex)s END,
                       CASE WHEN cast(%(name)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(name)s END)""", d_)
```

Error message:

```
----> 5  CASE WHEN cast(%(name)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(name)s END)""", d_)

ProgrammingError: column "age" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 2:                VALUES (CASE WHEN cast('' as text) IN ('', '#...
                               ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Maybe it is not possible to do this in psycopg2. Any help would be appreciated :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the result of the `CASE` expression (i.e. the value you're trying to insert) being TEXT, whereas the `age` column is INTEGER.

To address the error directly, you could simply cast the expression to `INTEGER`:

```
CASE WHEN cast(%(age)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(age)s END::INTEGER
```

Or

```
CAST(CASE WHEN cast(%(age)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE %(age)s END AS INTEGER)
```

However, unless you actually want an invalid cast exception when that field is anything other than an integer, and not one of the `('', '#', '-', '--', '??')` values you're specifically excluding, you might want to rewrite this particular statement as:

```
CASE WHEN age::TEXT ~ '^[\d]+$' THEN age ELSE NULL END::INTEGER
```

So check that's it actually a number before attempting to cast it, and if it's not a number then NULL it. But either way, you just need to cast the result. Note you may have to do the same for the `dob` column.

Comment: Thank you! However, I do not understand why the error - if the value of the key "age" is an empty string, it should be caught by the `CASE WHEN cast(%(age)s as text) IN...` expression, and `NULL` should be inserted. Otherwise, the value is an integer, and will be inserted. I am working with human-inputted data so any key can either be the correct type, or the human inserted a space or any of the chars I want to null. But I tested with a dictionary with correct types for the cols and this `INSERT` worked - it breaks when the value is not of the type of the col.

Comment: @TytireRecubans The result of the CASE expression will always be one data type, even if it's NULL. So in your original INSERT statement, whether the CASE returns NULL or an INTEGER, the data type of that value is TEXT - if nothing else, due to the cast of the input `age` to TEXT. Though presumably it's already TEXT at that point. So even if the value is an integer, it's held in a TEXT. If you simply did `INSERT ... VALUES ('1')`, because there is no explicit cast PG can implicitly cast it to the correct data type (INTEGER); but because it has an actual data type, it must be cast explicitly.

Comment: For example, `INSERT ... VALUES ('1'::TEXT)` when the field is INTEGER will fail due to the same error you're getting, because at that point the field is actually the TEXT data type. So you'd then have to cast that to INTEGER explicitly to insert it into an INTEGER field: `INSERT ... VALUES ('1'::TEXT::INTEGER)`. I don't know if this makes things any clearer? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jiJUtyLfhsoQqHBD8YABDB/0

Comment: I didn't understand the part about it breaking when the value is not the column type... which version breaks, mine or yours?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I understood, your code works, I didn't know that `The result of the CASE expression will always be one data type, even if it's NULL` - In this case my logic won't work, cuz I want to be able to check whether any value of the json I'm inserting is in the list of nullable value without knowing what the contraint of the table type is.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter substitution is not correct.  For example, instead of this:

```
%(CASE WHEN cast(age as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE age END)s
```

You should have:

```
(CASE WHEN cast(%(age)s as text) IN ('', '#', '-', '--', '??') THEN NULL ELSE age END)
```

Comment: I updated the code but I get a new error - which i don't get in the console :/